# How to omit aliased used in XMLForest function in oracle XML

Tags: oracle, plsql

pl SQL code segment
`SELECT Xmlserialize(DOCUMENT

                     XMLELEMENT("intrastat",
                     XMLAGG(
                            Xmlforest(ENVELOPE_ID AS "envID",
                            XMLFOREST(DATE_ AS "date",TIME_ AS "Time")AS "Date 
                                 time", PARTY_ID AS "pid",PARTY_NAME AS "pname", 
                                 XMLFOREST(Xmlelement("RC",REGION_CODE) AS RC,Xmlelement("TCPCODE",MODE_OF_TRANSPORT_CODE) AS TCPCODE) AS "item") 
)))
FROM INTRASTAT_XML_TEMPLATE_LINE_TMP`

part of actual output that make the trouble 
`<item><RC><RC>as</RC></RC><TCPCODE><TCPCODE>22</TCPCODE></TCPCODE></item>`

what i want to get
`<item><RC>ads</RC><TCPCODE>22</TCPCODE></item>`

Answer (score 0):

```
with data(rc, tcpcode) as (select 'ads', 22 from dual)
select xmlelement("item", xmlforest(rc, tcpcode)) from data;

XMLELEMENT("ITEM",XMLFOREST(RC,TCPCODE))                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<item><RC>ads</RC><TCPCODE>22</TCPCODE></item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current plsql code segment :

```
XMLFOREST(Xmlelement("RC",REGION_CODE) AS RC,Xmlelement("TCPCODE",MODE_OF_TRANSPORT_CODE) AS TCPCODE) AS "item")
```

And as we have used aliases in here, we are getting multiple tags - One for alias, and one for the first parameter of XMLELEMENT function.

Now, since you just want an element - `item`, with two tags - `RC` (holding data of `REGION_CODE` field) and `TCPCODE` (holding data of `MODE_OF_TRANSPORT_CODE` field), 
in my opinion, this should suffice your requirement:

```
Xmlelement("item", XMLFOREST(REGION_CODE "RC", MODE_OF_TRANSPORT_CODE "TCPCODE")
```

*~Kuntal*